# Is it possible to calculate the Chinese Zodiac, or must I use a lookup table?

Tags: data-structures, calendar, logic

I'm building an application that will tell your Chinese sign. I looked around but only found charts (from 1900 to 2020), and no logic to create something more dynamic.

Is there no logic for determining a Chinese zodiac?

Comment: I know that this question is not strong (is very weak), but is a logic problem, and I believe that suits the Q&A format.

Comment: As a rough estimation, just find the remainder of the year divided by 12.

Comment: @KennyTM Jan/Feb/Dez have problems following this logic.

Comment: What is "Dez"? Besides, the true Chinese Zodiac algorithm makes the division at Lichun which is almost always Feb 4th. (The common practice uses the Chinese calenders which starts at some seemingly arbitrary date in Gregorian calender that you'd like to use a table anyway.)

Comment: sorry, wrong language usage. Dec/Jan/Feb. My apologies. [This](http://www.chinese-astrology.co.uk/zodiactable.html#10) is the chart I was talking about. As you can see, the rotation does not start at Feb 4th. This is my problem, I'm not finding a good way to make a logic for a dynamic based system.

Comment: Right. Actually that's a common misconception, but anyway... If you want a longer table, start from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle. If you want to know the reasoning, StackOverflow is probably not the place to get the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does that answer your question:

```
public string ChineseZodiac(System.DateTime date)
{
    System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar cc = 
          new System.Globalization.ChineseLunisolarCalendar();
    int sexagenaryYear = cc.GetSexagenaryYear(date);
    int terrestrialBranch = cc.GetTerrestrialBranch(sexagenaryYear);

    // string[] years = "rat,ox,tiger,hare,dragon,snake,horse,sheep,monkey,fowl,dog,pig".Split(',');
    // string[] years = "Rat,Ox,Tiger,Rabbit,Dragon,Snake,Horse,Goat,Monkey,Rooster,Dog,Pig".Split(',');
    // string[] years = new string[]{ "rat", "ox", "tiger", "hare", "dragon", "snake", "horse", "sheep", "monkey", "fowl", "dog", "pig" };    
    string[] years = new string[]{ "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Goat", "Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig" };

    return years[terrestrialBranch - 1];
} // End Function ChineseZodiac
```

Fore those that need the source code for another programming language:

I've ripped the corresponding sources out of .NET Framwork, here:
https://gist.github.com/ststeiger/709354299a457e2d79b06d0127096fee

**Edit:** 
I ported this to JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.ChineseZodiac = void 0;
var DateTimeKind;
(function (DateTimeKind) {
    DateTimeKind[DateTimeKind["Unspecified"] = 0] = "Unspecified";
    DateTimeKind[DateTimeKind["Utc"] = 1] = "Utc";
    DateTimeKind[DateTimeKind["Local"] = 2] = "Local";
})(DateTimeKind || (DateTimeKind = {}));
var GregorianCalendar = (function () {
    function GregorianCalendar() {
    }
    GregorianCalendar.prototype.GetYear = function (time) {
        var ticks = time.JavaScriptTicks;
        var dt = new Date(ticks);
        return dt.getUTCFullYear();
    };
    GregorianCalendar.prototype.GetMonth = function (time) {
        var ticks = time.JavaScriptTicks;
        var dt = new Date(ticks);
        return (dt.getUTCMonth() + 1);
    };
    GregorianCalendar.prototype.GetDayOfMonth = function (time) {
        var ticks = time.JavaScriptTicks;
        var dt = new Date(ticks);
        return dt.getUTCDate();
    };
    return GregorianCalendar;
}());
var DotNetDateTime = (function () {
    function DotNetDateTime(ticks, dt) {
        this.m_ticks = 0;
        this.m_ticks = ticks;
    }
    DotNetDateTime.fromJsDate = function (dt) {
        var jsTicks = dt.getTime();
        var dotNetJsbaseTicks = 621355968000000000;
        var tenK = 10000;
        var dotTicks = dotNetJsbaseTicks + jsTicks * tenK;
        return new DotNetDateTime(dotTicks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    };
    Object.defineProperty(DotNetDateTime.prototype, "Ticks", {
        get: function () {
            return this.m_ticks;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(DotNetDateTime.prototype, "JavaScriptTicks", {
        get: function () {
            var dotNetJsbaseTicks = 621355968000000000;
            var dotNetTicksSince1970 = this.m_ticks - dotNetJsbaseTicks;
            var jsTicks = parseInt((dotNetTicksSince1970 / 10000).toString(), 10);
            return jsTicks;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
    });
    return DotNetDateTime;
}());
var MinLunisolarYear = 1901;
var MaxLunisolarYear = 2100;
var DaysPerYear = 365;
var DaysPer4Years = DaysPerYear * 4 + 1;
var DaysPer100Years = DaysPer4Years * 25 - 1;
var DaysPer400Years = DaysPer100Years * 4 + 1;
var DaysTo10000 = DaysPer400Years * 25 - 366;
var TicksPerMillisecond = 10000;
var TicksPerSecond = TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;
var TicksPerMinute = TicksPerSecond * 60;
var TicksPerHour = TicksPerMinute * 60;
var TicksPerDay = TicksPerHour * 24;
var MinTicks = 0;
var MaxTicks = DaysTo10000 * TicksPerDay - 1;
var MinValue = new DotNetDateTime(MinTicks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var MaxValue = new DotNetDateTime(MaxTicks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var Jan1Month = 1;
var Jan1Date = 2;
var nDaysPerMonth = 3;
var s_daysToMonth365 = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];
var s_daysToMonth366 = [0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335];
var s_yinfo = [
    [0, 2, 19, 19168],
    [0, 2, 8, 42352],
    [5, 1, 29, 21096],
    [0, 2, 16, 53856],
    [0, 2, 4, 55632],
    [4, 1, 25, 27304],
    [0, 2, 13, 22176],
    [0, 2, 2, 39632],
    [2, 1, 22, 19176],
    [0, 2, 10, 19168],
    [6, 1, 30, 42200],
    [0, 2, 18, 42192],
    [0, 2, 6, 53840],
    [5, 1, 26, 54568],
    [0, 2, 14, 46400],
    [0, 2, 3, 54944],
    [2, 1, 23, 38608],
    [0, 2, 11, 38320],
    [7, 2, 1, 18872],
    [0, 2, 20, 18800],
    [0, 2, 8, 42160],
    [5, 1, 28, 45656],
    [0, 2, 16, 27216],
    [0, 2, 5, 27968],
    [4, 1, 24, 44456],
    [0, 2, 13, 11104],
    [0, 2, 2, 38256],
    [2, 1, 23, 18808],
    [0, 2, 10, 18800],
    [6, 1, 30, 25776],
    [0, 2, 17, 54432],
    [0, 2, 6, 59984],
    [5, 1, 26, 27976],
    [0, 2, 14, 23248],
    [0, 2, 4, 11104],
    [3, 1, 24, 37744],
    [0, 2, 11, 37600],
    [7, 1, 31, 51560],
    [0, 2, 19, 51536],
    [0, 2, 8, 54432],
    [6, 1, 27, 55888],
    [0, 2, 15, 46416],
    [0, 2, 5, 22176],
    [4, 1, 25, 43736],
    [0, 2, 13, 9680],
    [0, 2, 2, 37584],
    [2, 1, 22, 51544],
    [0, 2, 10, 43344],
    [7, 1, 29, 46248],
    [0, 2, 17, 27808],
    [0, 2, 6, 46416],
    [5, 1, 27, 21928],
    [0, 2, 14, 19872],
    [0, 2, 3, 42416],
    [3, 1, 24, 21176],
    [0, 2, 12, 21168],
    [8, 1, 31, 43344],
    [0, 2, 18, 59728],
    [0, 2, 8, 27296],
    [6, 1, 28, 44368],
    [0, 2, 15, 43856],
    [0, 2, 5, 19296],
    [4, 1, 25, 42352],
    [0, 2, 13, 42352],
    [0, 2, 2, 21088],
    [3, 1, 21, 59696],
    [0, 2, 9, 55632],
    [7, 1, 30, 23208],
    [0, 2, 17, 22176],
    [0, 2, 6, 38608],
    [5, 1, 27, 19176],
    [0, 2, 15, 19152],
    [0, 2, 3, 42192],
    [4, 1, 23, 53864],
    [0, 2, 11, 53840],
    [8, 1, 31, 54568],
    [0, 2, 18, 46400],
    [0, 2, 7, 46752],
    [6, 1, 28, 38608],
    [0, 2, 16, 38320],
    [0, 2, 5, 18864],
    [4, 1, 25, 42168],
    [0, 2, 13, 42160],
    [10, 2, 2, 45656],
    [0, 2, 20, 27216],
    [0, 2, 9, 27968],
    [6, 1, 29, 44448],
    [0, 2, 17, 43872],
    [0, 2, 6, 38256],
    [5, 1, 27, 18808],
    [0, 2, 15, 18800],
    [0, 2, 4, 25776],
    [3, 1, 23, 27216],
    [0, 2, 10, 59984],
    [8, 1, 31, 27432],
    [0, 2, 19, 23232],
    [0, 2, 7, 43872],
    [5, 1, 28, 37736],
    [0, 2, 16, 37600],
    [0, 2, 5, 51552],
    [4, 1, 24, 54440],
    [0, 2, 12, 54432],
    [0, 2, 1, 55888],
    [2, 1, 22, 23208],
    [0, 2, 9, 22176],
    [7, 1, 29, 43736],
    [0, 2, 18, 9680],
    [0, 2, 7, 37584],
    [5, 1, 26, 51544],
    [0, 2, 14, 43344],
    [0, 2, 3, 46240],
    [4, 1, 23, 46416],
    [0, 2, 10, 44368],
    [9, 1, 31, 21928],
    [0, 2, 19, 19360],
    [0, 2, 8, 42416],
    [6, 1, 28, 21176],
    [0, 2, 16, 21168],
    [0, 2, 5, 43312],
    [4, 1, 25, 29864],
    [0, 2, 12, 27296],
    [0, 2, 1, 44368],
    [2, 1, 22, 19880],
    [0, 2, 10, 19296],
    [6, 1, 29, 42352],
    [0, 2, 17, 42208],
    [0, 2, 6, 53856],
    [5, 1, 26, 59696],
    [0, 2, 13, 54576],
    [0, 2, 3, 23200],
    [3, 1, 23, 27472],
    [0, 2, 11, 38608],
    [11, 1, 31, 19176],
    [0, 2, 19, 19152],
    [0, 2, 8, 42192],
    [6, 1, 28, 53848],
    [0, 2, 15, 53840],
    [0, 2, 4, 54560],
    [5, 1, 24, 55968],
    [0, 2, 12, 46496],
    [0, 2, 1, 22224],
    [2, 1, 22, 19160],
    [0, 2, 10, 18864],
    [7, 1, 30, 42168],
    [0, 2, 17, 42160],
    [0, 2, 6, 43600],
    [5, 1, 26, 46376],
    [0, 2, 14, 27936],
    [0, 2, 2, 44448],
    [3, 1, 23, 21936],
    [0, 2, 11, 37744],
    [8, 2, 1, 18808],
    [0, 2, 19, 18800],
    [0, 2, 8, 25776],
    [6, 1, 28, 27216],
    [0, 2, 15, 59984],
    [0, 2, 4, 27296],
    [4, 1, 24, 43872],
    [0, 2, 12, 43744],
    [0, 2, 2, 37600],
    [3, 1, 21, 51568],
    [0, 2, 9, 51552],
    [7, 1, 29, 54440],
    [0, 2, 17, 54432],
    [0, 2, 5, 55888],
    [5, 1, 26, 23208],
    [0, 2, 14, 22176],
    [0, 2, 3, 42704],
    [4, 1, 23, 21224],
    [0, 2, 11, 21200],
    [8, 1, 31, 43352],
    [0, 2, 19, 43344],
    [0, 2, 7, 46240],
    [6, 1, 27, 46416],
    [0, 2, 15, 44368],
    [0, 2, 5, 21920],
    [4, 1, 24, 42448],
    [0, 2, 12, 42416],
    [0, 2, 2, 21168],
    [3, 1, 22, 43320],
    [0, 2, 9, 26928],
    [7, 1, 29, 29336],
    [0, 2, 17, 27296],
    [0, 2, 6, 44368],
    [5, 1, 26, 19880],
    [0, 2, 14, 19296],
    [0, 2, 3, 42352],
    [4, 1, 24, 21104],
    [0, 2, 10, 53600],
    [8, 1, 30, 59696],
    [0, 2, 18, 54560],
    [0, 2, 7, 55968],
    [6, 1, 27, 27472],
    [0, 2, 15, 22224],
    [0, 2, 5, 19168],
    [4, 1, 25, 42216],
    [0, 2, 12, 41680],
    [0, 2, 1, 53584],
    [2, 1, 21, 55592],
    [0, 2, 9, 54560],
];

function GregorianIsLeapYear(y) {
    if ((y % 4) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((y % 100) != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return (y % 400) == 0;
}

function GetYearInfo(lunarYear, index) {
    if (lunarYear < MinLunisolarYear || lunarYear > MaxLunisolarYear) {
        throw new Error("year");
    }
    return s_yinfo[lunarYear - MinLunisolarYear][index];
}
function CheckTicksRange(ticks) {
    if (ticks < MinValue.Ticks || ticks > MaxValue.Ticks) {
        throw new Error("time");
    }
}
function GregorianToLunar(solarYear, solarMonth, solarDate) {
    var outData = { lunarYear: 0, lunarMonth: 0, lunarDate: 0 };
    var isLeapYear = GregorianIsLeapYear(solarYear);
    var jan1Month;
    var jan1Date;
    var solarDay = isLeapYear ? s_daysToMonth366[solarMonth - 1] : s_daysToMonth365[solarMonth - 1];
    solarDay += solarDate;
    var lunarDay = solarDay;
    outData.lunarYear = solarYear;
    if (outData.lunarYear == (MaxLunisolarYear + 1)) {
        outData.lunarYear--;
        lunarDay += (GregorianIsLeapYear(outData.lunarYear) ? 366 : 365);
        jan1Month = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Month);
        jan1Date = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Date);
    }
    else {
        jan1Month = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Month);
        jan1Date = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Date);
        if ((solarMonth < jan1Month) ||
            (solarMonth == jan1Month && solarDate < jan1Date)) {
            outData.lunarYear--;
            lunarDay += (GregorianIsLeapYear(outData.lunarYear) ? 366 : 365);
            jan1Month = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Month);
            jan1Date = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, Jan1Date);
        }
    }
    lunarDay -= s_daysToMonth365[jan1Month - 1];
    lunarDay -= (jan1Date - 1);
    var mask = 0x8000;
    var yearInfo = GetYearInfo(outData.lunarYear, nDaysPerMonth);
    var days = ((yearInfo & mask) != 0) ? 30 : 29;
    outData.lunarMonth = 1;
    while (lunarDay > days) {
        lunarDay -= days;
        outData.lunarMonth++;
        mask >>= 1;
        days = ((yearInfo & mask) != 0) ? 30 : 29;
    }
    outData.lunarDate = lunarDay;
    return outData;
}
function TimeToLunar(time) {
    var gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    var gy = gregorianCalendar.GetYear(time);
    var gm = gregorianCalendar.GetMonth(time);
    var gd = gregorianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(time);
    var ad = GregorianToLunar(gy, gm, gd);
    return {
        year: ad.lunarYear
    };
}
function GetSexagenaryYear(time) {
    CheckTicksRange(time.Ticks);
    var x = TimeToLunar(time);
    return ((x.year - 4) % 60) + 1;
}
function GetTerrestrialBranch(sexagenaryYear) {
    if (sexagenaryYear < 1 || sexagenaryYear > 60) {
        throw new Error("sexagenaryYear");
    }
    return ((sexagenaryYear - 1) % 12) + 1;
}
function ChineseZodiac(date) {
    var dotNetDate = DotNetDateTime.fromJsDate(date);
    var sexagenaryYear = GetSexagenaryYear(dotNetDate);
    var terrestrialBranch = GetTerrestrialBranch(sexagenaryYear);
    var years = ["Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Goat", "Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig"];
    return years[terrestrialBranch - 1];
}
exports.ChineseZodiac = ChineseZodiac;
```

Testing:

```
var exports = {};
// [copy-pasting above code]
exports.ChineseZodiac(new Date(1970,0,1))
exports.ChineseZodiac(new Date(2021,0,1))
exports.ChineseZodiac(new Date(2022,0,1))
```

all returns the same values as dotnet.

Comment: @iorgu: Sure, just look into the .NET Framework reference sources for ChineseLunisolarCalendar and EastAsianLunisolarCalendar .

Answer (score 4):

By using a calculator

```
2013-4=2009
2009/12= 167.41666
167*12=2004
2009-2004=5 (5 is snake which was the animal for 2013)
```

Comment: why isn't this the top answer?, pretty much solves the problem

Comment: Can you explain why these steps return the Chinese animal index?

Comment: @Jamisco: WTF ? 
Because it is WRONG ? 
Does it actually return CORRECT results for all dates ? 
Why does it only take the year, and not the date ? 
Certainly very wrong. 
The Chinese new year doesn't start on January 1st, but somewhere between January and February. 
The correct computation is: 
((x-4)%60)%12+1;
and x is the lunar year, not the gregorian year.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to calculate the year.

```
<?php

$year = 2013;
    switch (($year - 4) % 12) {
        case  0: $zodiac = 'Rat';       break;
        case  1: $zodiac = 'Ox';            break;
        case  2: $zodiac = 'Tiger';     break;
        case  3: $zodiac = 'Rabbit';    break;
        case  4: $zodiac = 'Dragon';    break;
        case  5: $zodiac = 'Snake';     break;
        case  6: $zodiac = 'Horse';     break;
        case  7: $zodiac = 'Goat';  break;
        case  8: $zodiac = 'Monkey';    break;
        case  9: $zodiac = 'Rooster';   break;
        case 10: $zodiac = 'Dog';   break;
        case 11: $zodiac = 'Pig';   break;
    }
    echo "{$year} is the year of the {$zodiac}.<br />";


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a reference to 2044.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac

Using Year of the Rat as an example (for years after 1984), it looks like Rat cycles every:

```
383, 353, 353, 383, 354 days
```

Notice the last cycle is `354` which is more than likely due to Leap Year.  Maybe using this formula, you can work out any year up to maybe 2100 or so.

I used the following `T-SQL` to deduce those numbers

```
select DATEDIFF(D,'02/2/1984', '02/19/1985')
select DATEDIFF(D,'02/19/1996', '02/6/1997')
select DATEDIFF(D,'02/7/2008', '01/25/2009')
select DATEDIFF(D,'01/25/2020', '02/11/2021')
select DATEDIFF(D,'02/11/2032', '01/30/2033')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about finding a non-tabular mechanism for calculating the years of the Chinese Zodiac, then I recommend looking at ['Calendrical Calculations, 3rd Edition'](http://www.calendarists.com/) which has (LISP) code to handle calculations for the Chinese New Year, and from that, deducing the Year of the <*relevant-animal*> is straight-forward.  That book covers many calendrical systems and is an interesting read.  Being a luni-solar calendar, the Chinese calendar is quite complex; the mathematics gets quite detailed.

It is probably simpler, and likely more compact, code-wise, to use a table, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a question what is quicker to test and verify.

When developing [chinese zodiac calculator](http://www.calculla.com/en/chinese_zodiac) on calculla, we decided to use lookup table - as this was just quicker and more convenient to code, than actually testing any algo for it (even if algo may be simple, you still need time to test it).

This lookup was not a big table and you can actually get the javascript code from source of our website.

Comment: Thanks for the "code" and tips :) I'm gonna give a look at it asap :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must create an array of the zodiac signs exactly as below

```
DECLARE sign : [array(1.....12)]
DECLARE year : INTEGER
sign(1) ← "Rat"
sign(2) ← "Ox"
sign(3) ← "Tiger"
sign(4) ← "Rabbit"
sign(5) ← "Dragon"
sign(6) ← "Snake"
sign(7) ← "Horse"
sign(8) ← "Goat"
sign(9) ← "Monkey"
sign(10) ← "Rooster"
sign(11) ← "Dog"
sign(12) ← "Pig" 
DECLARE X, Y, N : INTEGER
X ← (year - 4)
Y ← (X DIV 12) // DIV return only the natural number
Y ← (Y * 12)
N ← N + 1
OUTPUT sign(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function ChineseSign(ByVal DoB As Date) As String

    Dim CSign As String = ""
    Dim YearSign As New Short
    YearSign = Year(DoB) Mod 12

    '// Uncomment the following to use Feb 12th as New Year calculation //
    'If Month(DoB) = 1 Then
    'YearSign = YearSign - 1
    'If YearSign = 0 Then YearSign = 12
    'ElseIf Month(DoB) = 2 And DoB.Day < 12 Then
    'YearSign = YearSign - 1
    'If YearSign = 0 Then YearSign = 12
    'End If

    Select Case YearSign
        Case 1
            CSign = "Rooster"
        Case 2
            CSign = "Dog"
        Case 3
            CSign = "Pig (Boar)"
        Case 4
            CSign = "Rat"
        Case 5
            CSign = "Ox"
        Case 6
            CSign = "Tiger"
        Case 7
            CSign = "Rabbit"
        Case 8
            CSign = "Dragon"
        Case 9
            CSign = "Snake"
        Case 10
            CSign = "Horse"
        Case 11
            CSign = "Goat"
        Case 12
            CSign = "Monkey"
    End Select

    Select Case CSign
        Case "Ox"
            Return "an " & CSign
        Case Else
            Return "a " & CSign
    End Select

End Function
```